# What is the name of this plant with 5-petaled pink flowers?

Tags: identification, flowers

What is the name of this plant?

[image]

The image was from a China tour website, although it doesn't seem to be on that page anymore. I am not sure if it is also popular in America.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It appears to be Madagascar Periwinkle ([Catharanthus roseus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catharanthus_roseus)). It is an annual (tender perennial actually) commonly grown in parts of the United States where the summers are hot.

Comment: I agree with Eric and note that it is much less resistant to cold temperatures than many annuals like impatiens or petunias